# How can I get an element by ID from a specific class in HTML?

Tags: html

I have 2 unordered lists, each with a class of student1 and student2. Each unordered list has 3 items with the same id as the other list. Let's say I want to get the element of the id FN from student1. How is this possible?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>JavaScript Json</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Student Information</h1>
    <ul class="student1">
      <li id="FN"></li>
      <li id="SN"></li>
      <li id="AGE"></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="student2">
      <li id="FN"></li>
      <li id="SN"></li>
      <li id="AGE"></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"with the same id"* - You have invalid HTML.  From there, any targeting of those HTML elements by JavaScript or CSS will be unreliable.  You need to correct your HTML first.  Perhaps consider using `class` instead of `id` on those `<li>` elements.

Comment: you can't use same id for multiple controls, its not valid in HTML.

Comment: This is invalid, you shouldn't use the same `id` for more than one element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mixed class and id. An id has to be unique, so your list could look like this:

```
<ul id="student1">
   <li class="FN"></li>
   <li class="SN"></li>
   <li class="AGE"></li>
</ul>
<ul id="student2">
  <li class="FN"></li>
  <li class="SN"></li>
  <li class="AGE"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for.